# Debugging file scope in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, scope, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio 2012, I have this uber-simple C++ program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::cout;
    int i = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

In case you wonder, the "std::cout << std::cout" part is only to show that std:cout can be accessed within the scope of the function - yes, it's meant to print the pointer to the console.

So I set a breakpoint at "int i = 1". When the breakpoint triggers, I want to inspect std::cout from the Command Window (or Immediate Window), so I type:

> >Debug.Print std::cout

But it returns the following error:

> identifier "std" is undefined

I don't understand why this happens, std should be in the scope of the function which is being executed. The same goes for any other stuff coming from the #include directive, I just can't inspect it using Debug.Print. What do I use in Visual Studio 2012 to inspect EVERYTHING accessible in the execution scope? It seems I can only access local variables with Debug.Print.